# error during playing video in phonegap android using phonegap VideoPlayer Plugin

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, cordova, video-player

[VideoPlayer PLUGIN](https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer)
 here is how i add video.js :

```
<script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="js/video.js"></script>
```

now i create **package src/com/phonegap/plugins/video/VideoPlayer.java**   i am not sure is it c**orect or wrong ?** then in config.xml:

```
  <feature name="VideoPlayer">
      <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.video.VideoPlayer.java"/>
    </feature>
```

and then in home.html

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
window.plugins.videoPlayer.play("videos/1970.mp4");
});

</script>
```

**on running application getting error :**

```
 01-03 23:42:04.784: W/System.err(14212): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.phonegap.plugins.video.VideoPlayer.java
01-03 23:42:04.792: I/System.out(14212): Error adding plugin com.phonegap.plugins.video.VideoPlayer.java.
```

and failed to run application and getting error "**the application ha stopped unexpectedly**" pls tell me what am i doing wrong ?   i want to play local file already saved in WWW/video/1970.mp4

Comment: remove  .java from the name

Comment: yes it solved the error problem but still i m  failed to play the video whats the reason behind that

Comment: all issues resolved but i m getting alert(Cannot Play Video) Unsupported file Type         i m using .mp4  with android 2.2

Answer (score 0):

[nsawaya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1074714/nsawaya) has already answered it (.java extension is not needed), I'm adding these lines for further clarification on plugin.xml file.

```
<platform name="android">

    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="VideoPlayer">
            <param name="android-package" value="com.moust.cordova.videoplayer.VideoPlayer"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>

    <source-file src="src/android/VideoPlayer.java" target-dir="src/com/moust/cordova/videoplayer" />
    <source-file src="src/android/VideoPlayerView.java" target-dir="src/com/moust/cordova/videoplayer" />


    <source-file src="res/android/layout/video_player.xml" target-dir="res/layout" />
</platform>
```